# Extract text from within div tag using BeautifulSoup 4 in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract text from within div tag using BeautifulSoup4 and python. The following html code is stored in a file (example.html)

My HTML:

```
<table class="NZX1058422900" cols="20" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 1496px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<td class="A10dbmytr2499b">
<div class="VWP1058422499" alt="Total Cases: 5 - Level 1, Level 2, or On Hold 2 - Completed" title="Total Cases: 5 - Level 1, Level 2, On Hold 2 - Completed">5/2</div>
</td>
</tbody>
</table>

I want the output to look like below:
Total Cases: 
5 - Level 1, Level 2, or On Hold
2 - Completed
```

So far my code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
openFile = open("C:\\example.html")
readFile = openFile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(readFile, "lxml")
```

I have tried below code without any success:

```
soup.find("div", class_="VWP1058422499")
```

Can anyone help as how above data can be extracted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding the answer from @so1989 as you are also wondering how to print with the format you have specified, I would suggest this approach:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

openFile = open("C:\\example.html")
readFile = openFile.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(readFile, "lxml")
alt = soup.find("div", {"class":"VWP1058422499"}).get("alt").split()

for i, char in enumerate(alt):
    if char == '-':
        alt[i-2] = alt[i-2] + '\n'
    if char[0] in ['-', 'C', 'L', 'o']:
        alt[i] = ' ' + alt[i]

alt = ''.join(alt)
print(alt)
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! @so1989
But I get "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'" error on line:
alt = soup.find("div", {"class":"VWP1058422499"}).get("alt")

Any idea how to resolve this?
I am unable to execute .get method..

Comment: @LinuxUser can you post here url of website you're trying to scrape?

Comment: @LinuxUser I tested it with the html text you gave us reading from a file and it worked, could be any error related to the file location or a website url?

Comment: @so1989
Unfortunately, I can't. The URL is from my company's internal website which requires a login.

I can explain what I am trying to do.
I am trying to parse a report generated from SQL Server Reporting Services.
The report is little complex as it includes javascript, images, and dynamic content.

I am not sure if Python and Beautiful Soup is the right tool to parse reports generated from SQL Server Reporting Services. I have already tried using Selenium along with Python but didn't have any success either. 

Is there any other tool available that I should consider using?

Comment: @LinuxUser so the problem is how to get the html properly to parse it with `BeautifulSoup`? Maybe you should try to retrieve first the page by using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and then process the HTML content with `BeautifulSoup` as shown.

Also if the problem with processing the `alt` content is resolved when reading it from a file, I would suggest to make a different question to fix that and accept/close this one, as I think the given solutions are valid.

Answer (score 3):

```
alt = soup.find("div", {"class":"VWP1058422499"}).get("alt")
print(alt.text) #or just print(alt)
```

Comment: Kudos for you, I hope you don't mind that I have decided to improve your answer.